# Accessing kaggle datasets through its API

Tags: nlp, rstudio, kaggle

Im looking to work on some of the public datasets available on Kaggle.
Is it possible to access kaggle datasets through its API using RStudio??

cheers,
sup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Kaggle](http://kaggle.com/) just launched their public API in February 2018 (so earlier this year). According to their Github repository, [Kaggle/kaggle-api](https://github.com/Kaggle/kaggle-api), Kaggle has (at least to date) made their API accessible *`"using a command line tool implemented in Python"`*.

I too was excited to discover the existence of Kaggle's API, and, similarly, was also interested if someone had written an API wrapper package for interfacing with Kaggle's API in R. I couldn't find anyone who had, so I wrote one myself, which you can find here: https://github.com/mkearney/kaggler. It's literally been less than a week since I created the repo, so I can't speak to its reliability yet, but that for now it appears to be the best place to start. And, for the record, as long as people are willing to use it, I have every intention of maintaining at least minimal levels of support for the package (assuming no enthusiastic third parties step in with their own R packages), but the API itself is new so it could still be a few months before there is any real stable option.

;;

Also, although I understood exactly what you meant by your question, I think it's worth pointing out that, technically, Rstudio is an integrated development environment (IDE) and not necessarily the source/library/program that connects you to non-Rstudio web APIs. What you're actually looking for is an R extension/library/package that is designed to act as a wrapper/client/interface for Kaggle's API. Of course, this distinction is mostly trivial because if you work in Rstudio (an excellent, open-sourced R-centric IDE) to communicate with external API's like Kaggle's, then you **are** *`"access[ing] kaggle datasets through its API using RStudio"`*. But for the sake of giving credit where credit is due, it'd be more accurate to say that you are hoping to leverage **{Rstudio**} and the **{pkgname}** package to communicate with Kaggle's API via the **R environment**.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation. Appreciate it. So, from what I understand, I could try using the package that you´ve written for starters?

Comment: Yep! Just as long as you don't mind it being in early development!